# laravel 5.2 Restfull Api with admin panel stop working suddenly

Tags: laravel-5

I developed admin panel to add,edit,delete users in my website with Restfull Api. edit and delete work fine  but add not.
when I add user it may work or this error may appear

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
```

This is my routes

```
Route::resource('admin/users','AdminUser');
```

This is store function in Admin user resource

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //rules
        $rules = array(
            'name'       => 'required',
            'email'      => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6'

        );

        /*
           validate the data user
         **/
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);

         if ($validator->fails()) {
            return view('admin.User.create_user')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput(['page' => 'home']);
                                     }
       /*
           Store  the data user in the database
         **/ 
        $user = new User;
        $user->name =$request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password=bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $user->role='user';
        $user->save(); //error here
       //redirect
         return redirect('admin/users')->with('message', 'Successfully added user!');
    }
```

And this is create_user.blade.php

```
 @extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<section id="advertisement">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="{{asset('images/shop/advertisement.jpg')}}" alt="" />
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="left-sidebar">
                    @include('shared.sidebaradmin')
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="features_items"><!--features_items-->
                    <h2 class="title text-center">Add New Product</h2>

                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                           <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                     <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                @endif

                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/users')) }}

                  <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
                    {{ Form::text('name',null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                  </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
                  {{ Form::email('email',null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
                  {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirm Password') }}
                  {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>

                  {{ Form::submit('Add a new user !', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

                 {{ Form::close() }}


                 </div><!--features_items-->

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

Comment: {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/users')) }} this is a get request 

you should put the method 'method' => 'post'

Comment: This is Form open the default mehod is post  not html https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form